# What is the migration path for the userinfo.email deprecation for Google Cloud Endpoints apps?

Tags: android, ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-openid

I currently have both iOS and Android apps that use Google Cloud Endpoints pointing to a Google App Engine backend.  They have always relied on the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" scope that is apparently [being deprecated on September 1](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable), in favor of the "email" scope.

The problem is the client libraries (released two days ago, on 8/12!) generated by endpointscfg.py still seem to hard code the soon-to-be-deprecated scope.

In iOS, the google-api-objectivec-client library appears to have a flag GTM_OAUTH2_USES_OPENIDCONNECT that might switch to the proper scope, but this flag does not seem to be used anywhere.

It would be easy, of course, to manually modify the auto-generated libraries to use the "email" scope directly, and this even seems to work fine with my App Engine backend, but this certainly doesn't feel like the Right Way to do this deprecation migration.

Has anyone dealt with this yet, and found a better way?  The deprecation is in just two weeks, and I'd really prefer that my apps don't break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is that your apps are not going to break. The verbiage on that page is incorrect (and will be fixed). Thanks for pointing it out.

The old scope ("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email") is being *deprecated*, but it will still be *supported*.  We encourage new apps to use the new "email" scope (and will be updating our libraries to do the same).

By the way -- same is true for the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" scope.